# Unable to remove blank space from crystal report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to remove blank lines from the report which is created due to suppressing a null field. I have tried multiple solution such as

1. adding all the object to a text object and check "Suppress Embaded
   Blank field line"
2. tried different formulas.
   But no success.
   Here is a screen shot of result
   [image]

here is screen shot of the Fields Added to report
[image]

Formulas i have tried

```
//if({TableGeneric.IsTaxable}="Yes")  then false else true
NOT(isnull({TableGeneric.IsTaxable}))
//if {Table1.TaxTypeId} = "" then true
```

more over i dont want to add different sectin for each record
please guid me what i should do.

Comment: how did you add the line on report?

Comment: Are you Asking About Doted line?

Comment: yes... I assume question about dotted line

Comment: Siva if you are asking about The doted line, So it is not problem. The main problem is at freight charges. When it hides An unwanted space is shown at it place. I want to remove that space.

Comment: ok fine... can you edit the question heading its misleading your intentions

Comment: you need to select a option in section expert `Supress blank section`

Comment: Sory for misslead. I have tried this too but giving same result.

Comment: sorry didn't notice you have placed fields one by one so space is present as it is.. I can think of a way but before that what is the condition that is making this field not to display?

Comment: NOT(isnull({TableGeneric.IsTaxable})). This is the formula that is suppressing the field.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this but its bit a lenghty code:

you need to extend the logic to all formulas like:

`@Gross Amount` formula will be like:

```
if NOT(isnull({TableGeneric.IsTaxable})) = 'Gross Amount'
then 'Gross Amount'
else if NOT(isnull({TableGeneric.IsTaxable})) = 'VAT/ST'
then 'VAT/ST' 
else if NOT(isnull({TableGeneric.IsTaxable})) = 'Additional VAT/ST'
then 'Additional VAT/ST' 
else if NOT(isnull({TableGeneric.IsTaxable})) = 'Total Including VAT/ST'
then 'Total Including VAT/ST' 
else if NOT(isnull({TableGeneric.IsTaxable})) = 'Fright Charges'
then 'Fright Charges' 
else if NOT(isnull({TableGeneric.IsTaxable})) = 'Discount'
then 'Discount' 
//This formula will display the first row name. Here it will check for all the values one by one and displays the value that satisfies the condition
```

`@Gross Amount value` formula will be like:

```
 if NOT(isnull({TableGeneric.IsTaxable})) = 'Gross Amount'
    then databasefield.value
    else if NOT(isnull({TableGeneric.IsTaxable})) = 'VAT/ST'
    then databasefield.value 
    else if NOT(isnull({TableGeneric.IsTaxable})) = 'Additional VAT/ST'
    then databasefield.value 
    else if NOT(isnull({TableGeneric.IsTaxable})) = 'Total Including VAT/ST'
    then databasefield.value 
    else if NOT(isnull({TableGeneric.IsTaxable})) = 'Fright Charges'
    then databasefield.value 
    else if NOT(isnull({TableGeneric.IsTaxable})) = 'Discount'
    then databasefield.value
    //This formula will display the value of first row name. Here it will check for all the values one by one and displays the value that satisfies the condition
```

It should work.. don't have the tool right now but should work.

Comment: Thanks for help but it problem is still unsolved. I tried this but showing error "Boolean value required".

Comment: I am just new to CR, Infact I have started it just 3 days before, so i have no idea of it,s syntax and errors.

Comment: can you post screenshot of your formula?

Comment: i have mentioned it in my post.NOT(isnull({TableGeneric.IsTaxable})